# Datagrid: How to use hyperlink for something other than a URI?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, hyperlink

Is it possible to create a hyperlink column in a datagrid with entries that, when clicked, open a program or execute some other command other than executing a traditional URI (i.e., http or mailto)?

Answer (score 0):

This really depends on the files extension and the program they are assigned to open with on the users computer. Eg. A PDF may open in Adobe Acrobat.

Answer (score -1):

If the traditional URI isn't sufficient, you could handle the [click event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellcontentclick(v=vs.110).aspx), check to ensure it is in the correct column, and then open the file in the program of your choice.

Comment: The question is tagged `WPF` not `WinForms` so `CellContentClick` is irrelevant.